# How to convert a std shock to a unit shock in IRF from a VAR model in R?

Tags: r, time-series, var, standard-deviation

I am trying to find a way of converting a standard deviation shock to a unit shock in the impulse response functions from a VAR estimation obtained from the vars package. Any help would be much appreciated

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
data <- Canada[, c("prod", "e", "U", "rw")]
VAR1 <- VAR(data, p = 1, type = "both")
irf <- irf(VAR1, impulse="prod", response="e", n.ahead=8, boot=TRUE)
plot(irf)
```

This code generates an IRF when the shock is a standard deviation shock. I would like to obtain an IRF for a unit shock.